# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String get_Item(Int32)' method

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

I am trying to assign a value to a list of classes, but it doesn't seem to like "outside" values in my select statement.

Code in C# .dll file (compiles with no errors in Visual Studio):

```
    Dictionary<int, string> My_dict1 = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    My_dict1.Add(0, "Welcome");

    var inv = traces.Select(x => new TraceLabelData
    {
        Name = My_dict1[0]
    }).ToList();
```

Error when referenced and run in LINQPAD:

> NotSupportedException
>       LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String 
>       get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store 
>       expression.

If I replace My_dict[0] with a plain string it works, and if I replace it with variable that's a plain string it works. It doesn't work with the dictionary, and it doesn't work with function that returns a string.

Comment: What is `traces`, exactly? An `IQueryable<T>` (if so, what is `T`), a `DbSet<T>`, etc?

Comment: `string first = My_dict1[0];` then use it in select `Name = first`

Comment: @Dai, T is a custom class. I don't how to describe it much more than that. Anyways, I have your answer from below.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, the example I gave was simplified for my actual use which is that I'll be doing this at a higher, 2 dimensional (?) scale.

I.e. There is Name, Description, etc. and will be needing My_dict[0], [1], etc.

Thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq-to-Entities can only use Linq operations compatible with your back-end database server. Obviously your `My_dict1` object doesn't exist in the remote-server (i.e. you can't use it from raw SQL). Instead, pull your objects into memory using `AsEnumerable()`, `ToList()`, or `ToListAsync()` **before** getting your in-memory dictionary involved:

```
    Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    dict.Add( 0, "Welcome" );

    traces
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select( t => new TraceLabelData() { Name = dict[0] } )
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

The expressions that you pass to LINQ-to-Entities are not evaluated. They are parsed, then converted into SQL statements, which are then evaluated by the SQL Server. The server has no idea what your dictionary is, but it does know what a plain string is, which is why it works only when you change your code to use a string.

The solution in this case is to retrieve the value you need from the dictionary prior to your LINQ statement and then use the retrieved value directly.